# How can I make a Bootstrap horizontal grid work on mobile?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my html:

```
<div class="panel panel-default col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1">
 {% for t in usr %}<div class="col-2 col-sm-6-offset-1 col-md-4 col-lg-2 panel panel-default"><br>

  <span><span> <img src="{{ t.picture.url }}"  class="img-responsive" alt="My image" style="display: inline-block;
            left: 25%;
            position: relative;
             width: 45px;
            height: 45px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            background-size: cover;"/> </span></span><br>
  <h6 style="text-align: center"><a style="color: inherit;" href="/accounts/profile/{{ t.id }}">{{ t.user.get_full_name }}</a></h6>
{% if user != t.user %}<a href="{% follow_url t.user %}?next={{ request.path }}">{% endif %}
    <p style=" left: 10%;
            position: relative;">{% if user %}{% if user|is_following:t.user and user != t.user %}<span style="background-color: grey" class="btn btn-primary" aria-hidden="true">Unfollow | {{ t.followers }}</span> {% elif user != t.user %}<span class="btn btn-primary" aria-hidden="true">Follow  | {{ t.followers }}</span>{% elif user == t.user %}<span style="background-color: grey" class="btn btn-primary" aria-hidden="true">Followers | {{ t.followers }}</span>{% endif %}{% else %}
        <span style="background-color: grey" class="btn btn-primary" aria-hidden="true">Followers | {{ t.followers }}</span>
   {% endif %}</p></a>  </div>
{% endfor %}</div>
```

This displays:[image]

As you can see, it works just fine on the desktop.
However, when I run the exact same code on my phone, this is what I see. Everything else is fine, but this grid just goes crazy:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? As I said, the rest of the html works fine on my phone (It's not a separate mobile site or anything). This bootstrap grid is the only thing that's causing problems.

Comment: `col-2 col-sm-6-offset-1` looks weird for bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Remove `left` property from all of your `<span>`, `<p>` and `<img>` tags and edit your css as following this example:

```
span{
  display:block;
}
img{
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
p{
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
p.btn-primary{
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```